# Is there a way to resize on drag and drop in Aperture?

Tags: automator, gmail, aperture

My photos are mostly 4000 x 6000 pixels.

I want to email smaller ones.  I use gmail in a browser.

Right now to do this I need to:

- Select pictures
- Export versions - select a size
- Navigate in finder to the pictures
- Drag and drop to my open compose window.
- Clean up the created pix.

I can drag and drop full size pictures but an 6-8 megs each they make for obese email messages.

Is there a way to resize on drop?

Edit:

One comment asked about using an online drive, and working by reference.
Tried Google drive.  To hard to find a given image, even with a few hundred, as GD doesn't know how to search for keywords in images. I have 25,000 images.  I don't know which ones I will share ahead of time.  I  want to keep one canonical copy of an image.   I need to be able to search by keyword, and browse the results.

Apple Mail:  Does NOT thread the same way that GMail does. Does not label the way Gmail does.  I use Streak, an extension for Gmail, that allows me to 'hide' messages for later processing.  This is not compatible with Apple Mail.

E.g. I could, from Aperture email a set of photos at whatever reduction.  This breaks the thread.  Now, depending on whether the client responds to the Apple Mail message, or the previous gmail message, I will now have two threads from the same customer.  Viewing them sequentially is much more difficult.  Gmail has no tool for merging threads.

Comment: Instead of emailing the image files, have you considered sharing them in a service such as Dropbox or Google Drive? There may be other sharing services.

Comment: ..or using Apple's Mail, which adds a size parameter as soon as you drop an image into a mail.

Comment: Edited question in response to IconDaemon and Tetsujin